# Is there a way to employ the tab stop function on certain fields within my sub-form in datasheet view within the main form

Tags: ms-access-2016, subform, tabstop, datasheet

I have a sub-form where I have employed some tab stops when a user is entering some product details. They enter the part code, and the description and other known details autofill, so they then tab straight to a quantity field to input how many they want. Well that's the plan in any case, when I open the sub-form on it's own there is no issue, the tab stops work, however, when I open the main form it is a part of, the sub-form in it's datasheet view the tab stops do not engage. Am I missing something simple here? or can it not be done with datasheet views in this manner?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Must have been a coffee free morning, just figured out my own answer. The sub form on the main form was pulling directly from the query itself, and not via a form based on that query. Still, if it is possible to tab stop based on the query directly I'd be interested to know. Thanks and coffee is now in my cup.